# toggling opacity by jQuery after keyframes animation on element

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, opacity

i have an element `#show` that starts as visible on the page, disappears upon clicking a button (a 2nd element `#hidden` appears in its place), and then reappears the next time the button is clicked (`#hidden` disappears). i've animated `#show`'s opacity upon button click by jQuery.

however, i want to use keyframes animation on `#show`'s opacity as well, so that it fades nicely onto the page upon load. it seems that when i add the keyframes animation, it stakes claim to `#show`'s opacity permanently. the opacity stays at 1, and the jQuery code for `#show` no longer works.

i'm not sure if there's a different way to toggle `#show`'s visibility in the jQuery, or a keyframes alternative in jQuery. fadeToggle is not an option for this scenario because i need `#show`'s height to be preserved.

here's the keyframes on `#show`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade { 0% { opacity:0; } 50% { opacity:0; } 100% { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fade { 0% { opacity:0; } 50% { opacity:0; } 100% { opacity:1; } }
```

`#show`'s css:

```
#show {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: fade 1.5s;
}
```

and the elements' jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    if ($('#shown').css('opacity') == 1) {
        $('#shown').animate({opacity:0}, 250);
        $('#hidden').fadeToggle(250);
    }
    else {
        $('#hidden').fadeToggle(250);
        $('#shown').animate({opacity:1}, 250);
    }
});
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guwq51om/3/

tl;dr: can an element have an initial keyframes animation upon webpage load, and its opacity still be able to be toggled by jQuery?

Comment: simply remove `forwards`, it's the culprit and not needed since 1 is the default opacity

Comment: @TemaniAfif WOW OMFG... thank you so much. i would've never thought that my animate shorthand was the problem. i'll be reading the keyframes and animation docs more closely lol

Comment: This case is a bit tricky and even in the Doc you won't *explicitely* find it (you have to deduct it from different statements). I thought I have an answer about this but not able to find it ... I will write an answer to explain this if I don't find my old one